# p:pickList ignores attributes of <p:column>

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I am currently developing an application where the user can use a picklist to make certain associations.

I would like to display the object's attributes in different columns inside the picklist, for example the object car would display its id, year and color. However, the headerText of the column is not working. The column only displays the data but PrimeFaces seems to ignore the attribute **headerText** among others like sortBy. Is there any workaround? What am I doing wrong? p:column seems to work fine on a DataTable but not on a PickList and I really need to use a PickList or at least something with very similar functionalities.

Below is my code:

```
<p:pickList id="pickListAssociacao" value="#{associacaoPickListView.carsPickListView}" var="car" itemLabel="#{car.brand}" itemValue="#{car}">

<p:column headerText="Header1">
    <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
</p:column>

<p:column headerText="Header2" sortBy="#{car.year}">
    <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
</p:column>

<p:column headerText="Header3">
    <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
</p:column>

</p:pickList>
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: According to the PrimeFaces showcase,  `p;column`  works great in a picklist. It just does not support sorting and headers. Only, filtering and some others as described in the showcase and docs. So everything you see is 'normal'

Comment: Is there any workaround on this? Or should I use the picklist from RichFaces instead, since in their showcase http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=pickList, it seems that those attributes work on the picklist?